# exception MATCH rised in line 359

Tags: exception, isabelle

I have co-inductive *exec* and *eval*. For *eval* **code_pred** worked automaticaly, but for *exec* couldn't.
I added [code_pred_intro] lemmas according with [example with tranclp](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2016-1/dist/Isabelle2016-1/doc/codegen.pdf) (I ommit it becouse it takes several screens) and proofed it with

```
proof -
  case exec
  from this show thesis by (smt (verit) exec.cases)
qed
```

(This was proposed by sledgehammer) It worked and no goals left. But at `qed` error `exception MATCH raised (line 359 of "pattern.ML")` occured.

I tried to replace it with:

```
apply (smt (verit) exec.cases)
done
```

and

```
by (smt (verit) exec.cases)
```

but still have same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Please reduce your code to the smallest example that triggers this error and send it to cl-isabelle-users@lists.cam.ac.uk